# Switch locale in Storybook while using @angular/localize AOT

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, angular-localize

I have an Angular 16 app that uses the @angular/localize package to internationalize this app.
I also use Storybook in my development workflow, but I'm having a hard time combining the two.

I'm unable to figure out how to switch locales in Storybook without switching to runtime translations (which I prefer not to). Is this even doable?

It seems there is a mismatch between the @angular/localize AOT and the way Storybook renders the components (but I definitely can be mistaken).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.